# find the maximum value in a column with respect to other column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-analysis

i have below data frame:-

input-

```
  first_name last_name  age  preTestScore  postTestScore
0      Jason    Miller   42             4             25
1      Molly  Jacobson   52            24             94
2       Tina       Ali   36            31             57
3       Jake    Milner   24             2             62
4        Amy     Cooze   73             3             70
```

i want the output as:-0

Amy 73

so basically i want to find the highest value in age column and i also want the name of person with highest age.

i tried with pandas using group by as below:-

```
df2=df.groupby(['first_name'])['age'].max()
```

But with this i am getting the below output as below :

```
first_name
Amy      73
Jake     24
Jason    42
Molly    52
Tina     36
Name: age, dtype: int64
```

where as i only want

Amy 73

How shall i go about it in pandas?

Comment: I think you are looking for just `df.loc[df.age.idxmax(),['first_name','age']]`

Comment: @jezrael Since each `first_name` is unique, with your code, he will get the answer he is already getting.

Comment: @jezrael yes i was getting the same response , thank for help !!!

Comment: @moys yes i am getting the required result , but didn't understood , ill read about it.Thanks for help !!

Comment: @moys - reopened.

Comment: @jezrael Thanks. Added the answer with explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code should do the work

```
df[df['age']==df['age'].max()][['first_name','age']]
```

The `[['first_name','age']]` has the names of columns you want in the result output.
Change as you want.
As in this case the output will be

```
first_name  Age
Amy         73
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get your result with the code below

```
df.loc[df.age.idxmax(),['first_name','age']]
```

Here, with `df.age.idxmax()` we are getting the index of the row which has the maximum age value.

Then with `df.loc[df.age.idxmax(),['first_name','age']]` we are getting the columns 'first_name' & 'age' at that index.

Comment: is it possible to have both solutions combine like a data frame and the maximum value at the below of dataframe